# TFTP Client Won't Install for Vista cmd

Tags: command-line, windows-vista, tftp

I'm attempting to add the tftp client feature to the vista command line to do a simple networking exercise. I'm running Windows Vista (Home) on my laptop, and have tried to activate the feature from Programs and Features -> Turn On Windows Features -> TFTP Client.

The list of features comes up fine, but when I try to add or remove something, it just hangs up on the window saying "Please wait while these features are configured. This may take a few minutes".

I've waited upwards of half an hour, and the bar has not even begun to move. I'd like to know if anybody knows why this might be happening. I'd also accept a solution for installing the feature manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip this problem just download a TFTP Client from the internet:

Here's a few:

- [C# TFTP Client](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctftpclient/)
- [TFTP Client](http://www.tftp-server.com/tftp-client.html)
- [WinTFTP](http://www.wintftp.com/download.htm)